# Unable to get specific data from javascript object gotten from mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get specific info from a javascript object from a mongo database. My code is

```
    tags.find({tagName: tagArgs[1]}, function (err, tag) {
        if (err) {

            
        } else {
            msg.channel.send(tag.tagContent)
        }
    })
```

What I want happened is for the content of the tag to be sent, however, instead it sends nothing. If I instead did

```
msg.channel.send(tag)
```

I would get an object

```
{
  _id: 6071ce10c7b87d58acfeac7e,
  tagName: 'Test',
  tagContent: 'hello world',
  __v: 0
}
```

but trying to tap into tagContent returns nothing, what am I doing wrong?